# Kiel oni diras "incel" esperante?

Tags: single-word-requests

Por tiuj, kiuj ne scias la anglan vorton: Ĝi devenas el "involuntarily celibate", kaj la signifo estas "persono kiu volegas seksumi, sed ne povas, ĉar sia aspekto kaj/aŭ personeco tre mallogas". Tipe, "incel" estas amara mizogina komputila nerdo.

Mi ŝatas "malamindumulon" kaj "kontraŭvolan maldonĵuanon". Ĉu ekzistas establita vorto?

Answer (score 4):

Konsiderinda estas la radiko [`ĉast`](https://vortaro.net/#%C4%89asta_kd), kiu, inter aliaj, havas la signifon: *detenanta sin de ĉiaj seksrilatoj*.

Vi povas uzi `kontraŭvola ĉastulo` aŭ `nevola ĉastulo`. Depende de la kunteksto, ankaŭ `nevola ĉastanto` eblus (estas nuanco inter `-ul-`, kiu estas persono difinita de la ĉasteco, kaj `-ant-` kiu estas persono kiu nur ĉastas nun.

Ilian senton (tiun de la nevolaj ĉastuloj) oni povas priskribi ankaŭ per `ĉastigo` (tiu `-ig-` povas enkonduki la ideon de devigo, trudo aŭ nevolo). Do `ĉastigito` estus alia eblo.